# laravel 4.2 paginate load more button

Tags: php, laravel, pagination

Attempting to implement a 'Load More' button, via Laravel's paginate(). I'm getting hung up with the second db call, when requesting more. I've tried a few different variations but as you can see, it's completely incorrect.

Controller

```
public function displayItems() {
        $items = DB::table('stuff')->paginate(100);
        Session::put( 'items.page' , 0 );
        return View::make('pages/items', ['items' => $items]);
    }

public function displayMoreItems() {
    if ( Session::has( 'items.page' ) ) {
        $page = Session::get( 'items.page' ) + 1;
        Session::put( 'items.page' , $page );
        $items = DB::table('stuff')->paginate(100);
        return View::make('pages/items', ['items' => $items]);
    }
}
```

Route

```
Route::get( '/load/more' , [
    'as' => 'load.more' ,
    'uses' => 'LoadMoreController@displayMoreItems'
] );
```

Blade

```
@foreach($items as $item)
     <li>{{ $item->name }}</li>
@endforeach

<a id="load-more-btn" href="{{ route( 'load.more' ) }}" class="btn blue">Load More</a>
```

JS

```
$( '#load-more-btn' ).click( function (event) {

   event.preventDefault();

   $btn = $( this );

   $.ajax( {
      url : $btn.attr( 'href' ),
      dataType : 'html',
      timeout : 10000
   } ).done( function (data) {
      if ( !data ) { 
         $btn.hide();
         return;
      }
      $btn.before( data );
   } ).fail( function (jqXHR, textStatus, error) {
      if ( textStatus == 'timeout' ) {
         alert( 'Error, please try again later.' );
      }
      else { 
         alert( 'Error, please try again later.' );
      }
   } );
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try this:

```
public function displayItems() {
    $items = Stuff::paginate(100);
}
```

Note that:
`Stuff` is your model name.

Comment: I don't have a model setup. I get a class error when trying that. I've added my JS, although I don't see it as the issue, it could be wrong

Answer (score 0):

Add `\Input::merge(array('page', $page));` to the method `displayMoreItems()`.

Comment: Is that input being created by paginate? Otherwise nothing would be merged. I did try it though with no success